# How to do this calculation in java/groovy?

Tags: java, algorithm, math, groovy

I want a function that can do the below calculation and return the result. I am not sure what does **e** means in this statistical formula. I am not sure how to convert that formula to java code...that is the issue...specifically e power points....points is a variable which i will pass in as the function arg

[image]

**This is not homework.**

Comment: Is this homework? If so, add that tag. Then tell us what you've tried!

Comment: @NathanielFord this is not a home work. we have some statical models and i am creating oracle for that. do not down vote without having the right information. I have enough credits on SO to know when to use which tags

Comment: @Pangea I think you need to clarify your question a bit.  It would be nice to add what you've tried along with some further details such as what the range of Points is.  I almost feel bad saying this, but this question wreaks of "gimmetehcodez" in its current state.

Comment: @Corbin I am not sure how to convert that formula to java code...that is the issue...specifically e power points....points is a variable which i will pass in as the function arg

Comment: @Pangea I downvoted because you asked us to solve an open-ended problem, without presenting a specific issue or things you've tried. You did not even well-define the problem; if you don't know what e is, how can we?

Comment: @Pangea e is (probably) the base of the natural logrithm.  java.lang.Math.E in otherwords.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)

Comment: @Corbin - thx...this is what I didn't know.

Comment: @NathanielFord - people with mathematical and statistics knowledge would know what e is...like Corbin...and the assumption is that the only the person who understood the question will answer or comment

Comment: @Pangea I have to agree with Nathaniel. A variable only means what it's defined as.  e could easily be defined as 5.  It is just almost assumed to be the typical e (base of the natural logrithm, or one of the various other ways of defining it).  Also I think a lot of people were taken aback by the wording of the question.  You basically posted a specification for a function with no details of what you had tried or what specific problems you were having (though you did edit to mention that not knowing what *e* was was the problem).

Comment: @Corbin thx. Now that I edited it, i think the downvoters will rollback their down votes.

Comment: Maybe, but I doubt most of the down voters are still following this question.  And, in all honesty, `e` could probably be Googled meaning this question probably still deserves down votes.  (`e` may actually be hard to google though since it's just a letter.  I'm sure some combination of math/statistics and e would bring it up though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e` is a constant. Its value is `2.71828...`.

See [e math constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29)

Answer (score 5):

As Corbin said, you can find [your constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29) in Java as `java.lang.Math.E`.

But you probably want to use the `Math.exp(Double d)` method.

Your calculation is:

```
 ePoints = Math.exp(Points);
 finalScore = 1000 * (ePoints/(1 + ePoints)) - 10;
```

You can achieve better precision, but higher risk of overflow, by using:

```
 ePoints = Math.exp(Points);
 finalScore = (1000 * ePoints)/(1 + ePoints) - 10;
```

Comment: +1 I totally forgot about Math.exp =D

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if that is a know formula or not (maybe a scientific package has it), but this seems to work:

```
import static Math.pow

def finalScore(points) {
    def e = Math.E
    1000 * pow(e, points) / (1 + pow(e, points)) - 10
}

// lim when points -> 0 of finalScore(points) == 490
assert finalScore(0) == 490

// lim when points -> ∞ of finalScore(points) == 990
assert Math.abs(finalScore(50) - 990) < 0.001
```